# How do I create a record and have it relate to the parent in Google Apps Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

Probably such a basic question but having some issues.  I'm not a big developer; most of the stuff I've done has been in things like FileMaker or Salesforce where it's more limited coding.  I'm messing with Google App Maker and it seems really straightforward but I'm having issues with a basic function that I can't seem to find help on.  Everything else I have working fine.

Super basic example, let's say I have a table called Accounts, and then a related table called Contacts.  One Account can have many Contacts.  On the Account page I have a table that shows all the Contacts related to that Account.

From the Account page I have a button that opens a popup with another page to Create a Contact.  I'm just not clear on how I set it to relate that Contact to that Account and don't want to reinvent the wheel.  If I put the "Account" lookup field on the new Contact page, and manually select the Account when making the Contact, it of course works.  However if I'm on an Account page already, and I'm creating a Contact, I want that Contact to automatically be linked to that Account without having to manually select it.  Super straightforward, I'm just not clear on if there's a way to do this built in, or if I would be doing it as a custom action when using the OnClick event for the "Save" button on the new Contact window etc.  Or if I (hopefully not) have to do it via coding like under scripts.

Hope that makes sense, been reading guides and checking samples but thought I'd post instead.